# Ubuntu 18.04 keeps freezing randomly after some time

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 18.04, freeze

I have Ubuntu 18.04 running in a dual boot setup along with Windows 8.1 From the past 3 days, Ubuntu has become completely unusable on my laptop because it keeps freezing randomly after some time. I already had network issues with Ubuntu wherein my Wifi would randomly disconnect after some time and my Wifi connection would become invisible. I sometimes had to turn off my Wifi for 5-10 minutes and then it would reconnect and the internet would work.

Till yesterday, I was getting some errors related to inodes on a black screen during startup. I have posted images of those messages. Also, when my laptop froze, I was ableto restart it by pressing `Alt` + `Sys Rq` + `reisub`, but today even this has stopped working. I have to turn it off using the power button on the laptop and then turn it back again.

Havent installed any new programs recently, just an update about 4-5 days ago.

[image][image]

Heres the output of `cat /var/log/syslog` from around the time when Ubuntu froze:

```
Jul 24 17:50:41 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e reason=4 locally_generated=1
Jul 24 17:50:41 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jul 24 17:50:41 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <warn>  [1627129241.2623] sup-iface[0x55e164524190,wlp8s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul 24 17:50:41 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129241.2936] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul 24 17:50:41 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129241.3684] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 24 17:50:41 homepc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3331]: [3978:4008:0724/175041.677431:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(429)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e (SSID='MY-WIFI' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc kernel: [ 5167.460108] wlp8s0: authenticate with 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129248.2617] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc kernel: [ 5167.477284] wlp8s0: send auth to 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e (try 1/3)
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: Trying to associate with 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e (SSID='MY-WIFI' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc kernel: [ 5167.480795] wlp8s0: authenticated
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc kernel: [ 5167.483170] wlp8s0: associate with 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e (try 1/3)
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129248.2704] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: Associated with 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not associated
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc kernel: [ 5167.493682] wlp8s0: RX AssocResp from 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc kernel: [ 5167.493752] wlp8s0: associated
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129248.2836] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129248.3852] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e completed [id=0 id_str=]
Jul 24 17:50:48 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129248.3910] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul 24 17:53:27 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e reason=4 locally_generated=1
Jul 24 17:53:27 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jul 24 17:53:27 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <warn>  [1627129407.2901] sup-iface[0x55e164524190,wlp8s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul 24 17:53:27 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129407.3130] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul 24 17:53:27 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129407.3962] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 24 17:53:27 homepc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3331]: [3978:4008:0724/175327.694647:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(429)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e (SSID='MY-WIFI' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc kernel: [ 5333.489903] wlp8s0: authenticate with 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129414.2937] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc kernel: [ 5333.506841] wlp8s0: send auth to 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e (try 1/3)
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: Trying to associate with 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e (SSID='MY-WIFI' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc kernel: [ 5333.528711] wlp8s0: authenticated
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc kernel: [ 5333.532733] wlp8s0: associate with 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e (try 1/3)
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129414.3211] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: Associated with 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not associated
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc kernel: [ 5333.584706] wlp8s0: RX AssocResp from 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc kernel: [ 5333.584807] wlp8s0: associated
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129414.3776] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129414.4642] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e completed [id=0 id_str=]
Jul 24 17:53:34 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <info>  [1627129414.4701] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jul 24 17:54:06 homepc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3331]: [3978:4008:0724/175406.598728:ERROR:connection_handler_impl.cc(471)] Timed out waiting for GCM Protocol buffer.
Jul 24 17:54:45 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=98:da:c4:3b:f4:6e reason=4 locally_generated=1
Jul 24 17:54:45 homepc NetworkManager[1549]: <warn>  [1627129485.2659] sup-iface[0x55e164524190,wlp8s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jul 24 17:54:45 homepc wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlp8s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
```

EDIT: Here's the O/P of some commands:

Output of `free -h`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        1.8G        2.9G        507M        3.0G        5.1G
Swap:          3.9G          0B        3.9G
```

Output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`:

```
9ECN31WW(V1.14)
```

Motherboard information:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t 2
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 16 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: Lenovo Y50-70
    Version: 31900059WIN
    Serial Number: CB33028468
    Asset Tag: 31900059WIN
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

[image]

EDIT: O/P of `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*`:

```
username@homepc:~$ grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*
Binary file /var/log/syslog matches
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 00:31:04 homepc smartd[1528]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 104 to 103
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 00:56:54 homepc kernel: [14114.668163] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 00:56:54 homepc kernel: [14114.687786] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 00:56:54 homepc kernel: [14116.007893] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 00:56:57 homepc systemd-sleep[15630]: /dev/sda:
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 08:27:53 homepc kernel: [14163.818811] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 08:27:53 homepc kernel: [14163.841427] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 08:27:53 homepc kernel: [14165.158971] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 08:27:56 homepc systemd-sleep[16051]: /dev/sda:
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 08:32:40 homepc smartd[1528]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 3 Spin_Up_Time changed from 184 to 183
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 08:32:40 homepc smartd[1528]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 103 to 116
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 09:01:05 homepc smartd[1528]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 116 to 107
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 09:31:04 homepc smartd[1528]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 107 to 106
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 10:01:04 homepc smartd[1528]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 106 to 105
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 10:31:04 homepc smartd[1528]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 105 to 104
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc systemd-fsck[828]: /dev/sda2: 177 files, 8633/65536 clusters
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc smartd[1693]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc smartd[1693]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc smartd[1693]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], WDC WD10S21X-24R1BT0-SSHD-8GB, S/N:WD-WX31A2408851, WWN:5-0014ee-6af828dc8, FW:03.01A01, 1.00 TB
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc smartd[1693]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc smartd[1693]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc smartd[1693]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_WD10S21X_24R1BT0_SSHD_8GB-WD_WX31A2408851.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc kernel: [    5.784767] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc kernel: [    5.784768] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc kernel: [    5.784788] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc kernel: [    5.784790] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc kernel: [    5.784835] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc kernel: [    5.916780]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 sda8 sda9 sda10 sda11 sda12 sda13
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc kernel: [    5.917637] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc kernel: [    9.848303] EXT4-fs (sda13): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc kernel: [   16.425279] EXT4-fs (sda13): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:49 homepc kernel: [   33.962702] Adding 4094972k swap on /dev/sda8.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:4094972k FS
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:50 homepc smartd[1693]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 3 Spin_Up_Time changed from 183 to 182
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:50 homepc smartd[1693]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 104 to 102
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:01:50 homepc smartd[1693]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_WD10S21X_24R1BT0_SSHD_8GB-WD_WX31A2408851.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 12:31:50 homepc smartd[1693]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 102 to 103
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc systemd-fsck[976]: /dev/sda2: 177 files, 8633/65536 clusters
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc smartd[1608]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc smartd[1608]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc smartd[1608]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], WDC WD10S21X-24R1BT0-SSHD-8GB, S/N:WD-WX31A2408851, WWN:5-0014ee-6af828dc8, FW:03.01A01, 1.00 TB
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc smartd[1608]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc kernel: [    5.781070] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc kernel: [    5.781072] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc kernel: [    5.781104] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc kernel: [    5.781106] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc kernel: [    5.781140] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc kernel: [    5.826074]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 sda8 sda9 sda10 sda11 sda12 sda13
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc kernel: [    5.826717] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc kernel: [    8.746930] EXT4-fs (sda13): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc kernel: [   11.012288] EXT4-fs (sda13): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:20 homepc kernel: [   32.179756] Adding 4094972k swap on /dev/sda8.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:4094972k FS
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:21 homepc smartd[1608]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:21 homepc smartd[1608]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_WD10S21X_24R1BT0_SSHD_8GB-WD_WX31A2408851.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:21 homepc smartd[1608]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 3 Spin_Up_Time changed from 182 to 181
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:21 homepc smartd[1608]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 103 to 101
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:25:21 homepc smartd[1608]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_WD10S21X_24R1BT0_SSHD_8GB-WD_WX31A2408851.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 16:55:21 homepc smartd[1608]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 101 to 102
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc systemd-fsck[979]: /dev/sda2: 177 files, 8633/65536 clusters
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc kernel: [    5.796827] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc kernel: [    5.796829] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc kernel: [    5.796851] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc kernel: [    5.796853] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc kernel: [    5.796904] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc kernel: [    5.841568]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 sda8 sda9 sda10 sda11 sda12 sda13
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc kernel: [    5.842333] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc kernel: [    7.256732] EXT4-fs (sda13): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc kernel: [    9.923139] EXT4-fs (sda13): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc kernel: [   33.960679] Adding 4094972k swap on /dev/sda8.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:4094972k FS
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc smartd[1469]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc smartd[1469]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc smartd[1469]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], WDC WD10S21X-24R1BT0-SSHD-8GB, S/N:WD-WX31A2408851, WWN:5-0014ee-6af828dc8, FW:03.01A01, 1.00 TB
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:31 homepc smartd[1469]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:32 homepc smartd[1469]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:32 homepc smartd[1469]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_WD10S21X_24R1BT0_SSHD_8GB-WD_WX31A2408851.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:32 homepc smartd[1469]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 3 Spin_Up_Time changed from 181 to 182
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:09:33 homepc smartd[1469]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_WD10S21X_24R1BT0_SSHD_8GB-WD_WX31A2408851.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 18:39:33 homepc smartd[1469]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 102 to 101
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 19:09:33 homepc smartd[1469]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 101 to 102
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 19:39:33 homepc smartd[1469]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 102 to 103
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc systemd-fsck[977]: /dev/sda2: 177 files, 8633/65536 clusters
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc kernel: [    5.809158] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc kernel: [    5.809160] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc kernel: [    5.809166] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc kernel: [    5.809167] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc kernel: [    5.809176] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc kernel: [    5.852467]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 sda8 sda9 sda10 sda11 sda12 sda13
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc kernel: [    5.853274] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc kernel: [    6.742457] EXT4-fs (sda13): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc kernel: [   10.357071] EXT4-fs (sda13): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc kernel: [   32.367334] Adding 4094972k swap on /dev/sda8.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:4094972k FS
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc smartd[1585]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc smartd[1585]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc smartd[1585]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], WDC WD10S21X-24R1BT0-SSHD-8GB, S/N:WD-WX31A2408851, WWN:5-0014ee-6af828dc8, FW:03.01A01, 1.00 TB
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:07 homepc smartd[1585]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:08 homepc smartd[1585]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:08 homepc smartd[1585]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_WD10S21X_24R1BT0_SSHD_8GB-WD_WX31A2408851.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:08 homepc smartd[1585]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 3 Spin_Up_Time changed from 182 to 181
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:08 homepc smartd[1585]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 103 to 101
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:15:09 homepc smartd[1585]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_WD10S21X_24R1BT0_SSHD_8GB-WD_WX31A2408851.ata.state
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 24 20:45:09 homepc smartd[1585]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 101 to 102
Binary file /var/log/syslog.1 matches
```

O/P of `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` was empty

Temperatures using `freon`:
[image]

Output of `sudo lshw -C memory`:

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: 9ECN43WW(V3.03)
       date: 08/12/2015
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 6592KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: b
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: c
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: d
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-cache
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: a
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
       configuration: level=1
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 2a
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: M471B1G73DB0-YK0
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: E187FF61
          slot: DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: Empty
          vendor: Empty
          physical id: 1
          serial: Empty
          slot: DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: Empty
          vendor: Empty
          physical id: 2
          serial: Empty
          slot: DIMM2
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: Empty
          vendor: Empty
          physical id: 3
          serial: Empty
          slot: DIMM3
```

Output of `grep -i pag /var/log/syslog*`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/X3GKD2kFWM/

Output of `grep -i swap /var/log/syslog*`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9wgkVNGzdD/

Output of `ls -al /boot`:

```
total 107216
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Jul 24 08:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root     4096 Jul 23 08:58 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217414 Jun 18 22:19 config-4.15.0-147-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217414 Jul 10 01:49 config-4.15.0-151-generic
drwx------  4 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Jul 22 08:01 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 41845448 Jul 21 08:43 initrd.img-4.15.0-147-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 41844884 Jul 24 08:29 initrd.img-4.15.0-151-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  4082393 Jun 18 22:19 System.map-4.15.0-147-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4082629 Jul 10 01:49 System.map-4.15.0-151-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8449696 Jun 19 00:12 vmlinuz-4.15.0-147-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8453792 Jul 10 01:53 vmlinuz-4.15.0-151-generic
```

This was the screen I saw when even rebooting froze (it wouldnt proceed further):

[image]
[image]

EDIT: Downgrading to the previous kernel (version -147) solved these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks very familiar to [Ubuntu 18.04.05 LTS Desktop hangs with since kernel 4.15.0-151 and systemd 237-3ubuntu10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353859/ubuntu-18-04-05-lts-desktop-hangs-with-since-kernel-4-15-0-151-and-systemd-237-3)

Try downgrading the kernel to the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

**file system**

At the initramfs prompt, type:

`fsck -f /dev/sda13`

**Paging fault**

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffff92d742a2bad4
```

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**BIOS**

Lenovo Y50-70

You have a very old BIOS version 9ECN31WW(V1.14). A newer BIOS 9ECN43WW(V3.03) can be downloaded [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-y-series-laptops/y50-70-touch-notebook-lenovo/downloads/DS100998).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your computer model.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Temperature**

If syslog's are to be believed, your machine is burning up.

Is the fan working on your laptop? Have you ever opened your laptop and cleaned out dust?

Install either `freon` or `vitals` gnome-shell extensions and check your CPU temps.

Or install `lm-sensors` and `psensor` and `xsensors` and check temps that way.

Comment: I have updated the question to add O/P of the commands you mentioned. At the initramfs prompt I did run `fsck /dev/sda13` and the process completed after I entered `YES` for all the prompts. I then had to type `reboot` to restart. I am running the memory test right now, will post here after it ends.

Comment: @StupidMan You didn't type the exact fsck commands in my answer. No matter at this point. Please see the BIOS update in my answer.

Comment: Just a hint, I had a similar problem with bionic installed on my device. It was freezing after some minutes since the last kernel upgrade a few days ago. Maybe the solution is booting an older kernel and do a release upgrade to focal (testing now).

Comment: @heynnema Yes correct model. I forgot to mention another problem that I have been facing since these issus started, the file system turns read only sometimes. It happened again a few minutes ago so I had to restart. Then I again got the initramfs prompt. There I typed the exact same command this time: `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda13` however it said sudo is not available so I removed the sudo and then ran it to completion (lots of yes prompts). Is there a way I can confirm if my hard disk is OK? Based on what I read on some other threads, I think my HDD might be dying. Will post another update soon.

Comment: Do you have Windows on this computer? If so, when was the last time you used it? Do you have a Windows driver installed that allows you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? Start the `Disks` app, and get screenshots of the **SMART Data** window. This data is scrollable, so make sure you get it all.

Comment: @heynnema Yes I do have Windows on this machine and I was using it just a few hours ago. No I currently do not have any driver/software which allows me to read/write Linux filesystem in Windows.

I started the Disks app on Ubuntu but I couldnt find any SMART data window there. I have posted a screenshot in the question details at the end.

Comment: In `Disks`, click the 3-dot button, then you'll find SMART. I don't see the screenshot you refer to.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry I am having lots of network issues in Ubuntu so couldnt post it. I have posted it now. Please check it.

Comment: SMART looks fine. Edit your question and show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*`. If that output is large, then use paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: @heynnema The memory tests passed with 0 errors, I have also updated the BIOS to the latest version available but I am still facing the same issues. Also posted the O/Ps of the commands you posted in the last comment. Can you please take a look again?

Comment: @StupidMan Please see the temperature update in my answer.

Comment: @heynnema Yes I was shocked to see those temperatures but I am really not sure if those values are correct. I have been monitoring CPU temp on Windows (using Speccy) since I posted that and so far the temp has neer exceeded 60 degree celsius. Also since everything is working great in Windows, I think it might be a software issue with Ubuntu rather than a hardware issue. Anyway, since I havent cleaned the fan dust even once, I will try doing it tomorrow and see if the issue persists.

Comment: @StupidMan Install one of the utilities in Ubuntu to monitor your temps. Tomorrow, clean the fan, and other parts, from the dust bunnies.

Comment: @heynnema It happened again while I was using Ubuntu and I noticed the temperatures were well within 60 degree celsius throughout. I have posted a screenshot of the temps I am seeing with `freon`. Why is it showing 0 degrees?

Comment: @StupidMan Those must be invalid sensors. The only ones that you need to checkmark are "package id 0" and "WDC". Have you already cleaned your computer?

Comment: @StupidMan For lack of more diagnosable information... if you remember what time your last problem occurred, then `more /var/log/syslog` and look around that time for any clues. You'll know you're at the right place because the time will first be different when you rebooted your machine. We need to see right before the reboot.

Comment: @heynnema No I havent cleaned it yet because I dont have the tools to open it right now. I will doing it tomorrow. I have been checking `/var/log/syslog` ever since these issues started but I havent been able to find something helpful so far. This issue last occurred at 22:14, I have posted the logs from around that time here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Fqq7Z7VkJK/
The `sysrq` and `Emergency sync completed`at the end are showing up because I tried `Alt` + `Sys Rq`  + `reisub` after my screen froze.

Comment: @StupidMan As per my updated answer, you're getting paging faults: `BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffff92d742a2bad4`. You upgraded the BIOS, and ran memory test. You may not be able to fix this. Do `sudo lshw -C memory` and `grep -i pag /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i swap /var/log/syslog*` and `ls -al /boot`.

Comment: @heynnema I have updated my question to add these details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127903/discussion-between-heynnema-and-stupid-man).