# Ubuntu 18.04.05 LTS Desktop hangs with since kernel 4.15.0-151 and systemd 237-3ubuntu10

Tags: 18.04, kernel

Several crashes in /var/crash, here's the last one:-

```
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.
Date: Fri Jul 23 18:10:54 2021
Failure: oops
OopsText:
 BUG: Bad rss-counter state mm:00000000c098a229 idx:2 val:-1
 usblp0: removed
 usblp 1-5:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 3 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04F9 pid 0x02EC
 <44>[   18.329026] systemd-journald[358]: File /var/log/journal/b022dca21fd4480baeeb84f47ab439d3/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
 vboxdrv: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
 vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
 vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores
 vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 2303999142 Hz
 vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 6.1.24 r145767 (interface 0x00300000)
 VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
 VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
 Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
 Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
 Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
 rfkill: input handler disabled
 [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0f1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:80:20:da:95:bc:56:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
 [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:80:20:da:95:bc:56:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
 [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0f1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:80:20:da:95:bc:56:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
 [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:80:20:da:95:bc:56:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
 [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0f1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:80:20:da:95:bc:56:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
 [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:80:20:da:95:bc:56:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
 
Package: linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic 4.15.0-151.157
SourcePackage: linux
Tags: kernel-oops
Uname: Linux 4.15.0-151-generic x86_64
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The system is a laptop from Entroware based on Clevo and has 8 logical CPUs:-
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             2000.295
CPU max MHz:         4000.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            4599.93
Virtualisation:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d

USB Config:-
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:2110 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f9:02ec Brother Industries, Ltd MFC-J870DW
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0d8c:0104 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM103+ Audio Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

PCI Config:-
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e10 (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a335 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a336 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 93)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

This has only started happening since using 4.15.0-151. Reverting to 4.15.0-147 makes the system stable.

Comment: Do other people also experience more weirdness than just crashes? I notice my keypresses sometimes being missed, sometimes being slow - on top of the crashes that happen at shutdown, sleep, etc.

Comment: I have the same problem, though I couldn't narrow it down any more than this; booting 4.15.0-147 results in a rock solid system, 4.15.0-151 crashes randomly (3 crashes within the first hour after the update).

Answer (score 4):

Can also confirm, same here - this post made my day to see I am not alone.
I was almost sure my mainboard would be fault, as SMART and memtest reported no errors.

As addition to the above behavior very often suspend/resume and even restart was hanging.

As this was a security update (https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5018-1), it seems that speed was more important than stability testing...

I used the instructions here for downgrading the kernel: [How to downgrade kernel after bad update (16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945403/how-to-downgrade-kernel-after-bad-update-16-04)

(and remember to re-enable after a new fixed kernel is available, it's important due to the security issues)

Answer (score 4):

Issue is being tracked here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1938013.

Comment: I also had several lock-ups per day that appeared two days ago out of nowhere (I don't remember exactly when I ran my last update). I just installed the new kernel with the fix (thanks for working on that!), and things seem to run smooth again, I hope that solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have precisely the same symptoms.  Starting Friday, immediately after doing updates, I had occasional lock-ups that only a full power-off and power-on could recover from, I had my swap partition corrupted and had to reformat it, had to do a rescue on one NVMe root partition as well as two external drives before I reverted my kernel back to 4.15.0-147 and magically.. everything worked flawlessly again.  I wasted my weekend trying to understand what was going wrong until I figured out it was the kernel.  I also have a BUNCH of crashes from the kernel in /var/crash to show for it too.

```
miles@unicron:/var/crash$ ls -latr linux*
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie  763 Jul 21 13:57 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.32331.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie  763 Jul 21 14:33 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.32439.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie  988 Jul 21 14:34 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.53592.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie 3464 Jul 21 14:52 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.271760.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie 3677 Jul 22 03:52 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.258222.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie  736 Jul 22 19:17 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.32747.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie  742 Jul 22 19:17 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.32859.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie  455 Jul 23 03:04 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.13044.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie  530 Jul 23 13:06 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.20048.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie  673 Jul 23 13:14 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.30505.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie 1893 Jul 23 22:57 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.123785.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie 4163 Jul 23 23:28 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.305134.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie 1013 Jul 24 06:57 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.48875.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie 1209 Jul 24 07:01 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.65884.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie 2516 Jul 24 07:02 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.165751.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie 2678 Jul 24 07:07 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.178891.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie 3500 Jul 25 11:32 linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.253271.crash
```

Sample from `linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic.253271.crash`:

```
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.
Date: Sun Jul 25 11:32:27 2021
Failure: oops
OopsText:
 general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
 Modules linked in: xfs libcrc32c uas usb_storage rfcomm ccm ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter v4l2loopback(OE) snd_hrtimer cmac bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi nvidia_drm(POE) intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal nvidia_modeset(POE) intel_powerclamp coretemp arc4 kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_codec_realtek ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec_generic nvidia(POE) pcbc iwlmvm mac80211 snd_hda_intel aesni_intel snd_hda_codec aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper asus_nb_wmi cryptd asus_wmi snd_hda_core intel_cstate snd_hwdep intel_rapl_perf serio_raw sparse_keymap intel_wmi_thunderbolt iwlwifi snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event cfg80211 uvcvideo btusb btrtl videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm snd_rawmidi videobuf2_memops btintel videobuf2_v4l2 drm_kms_helper
  bluetooth snd_seq xpad videobuf2_core ff_memless ecdh_generic drm videodev snd_seq_device snd_timer media fb_sys_fops snd syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt mei_me idma64 soundcore virt_dma input_leds joydev mei processor_thermal_device intel_lpss_pci int340x_thermal_zone shpchp intel_pch_thermal intel_lpss intel_soc_dts_iosf elan_i2c mac_hid asus_wireless int3400_thermal acpi_pad acpi_thermal_rel sch_fq_codel ppa parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_asus hid_generic usbhid nvme r8169 ahci nvme_core mii libahci wmi i2c_hid hid video pinctrl_sunrisepoint
 CPU: 4 PID: 81 Comm: kswapd0 Tainted: P           OE    4.15.0-151-generic #157-Ubuntu
 Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. G752VT/G752VT, BIOS G752VT.213 01/06/2016
 RIP: 0010:find_get_entries+0x68/0x200
 RSP: 0018:ffffb54cc384f9d0 EFLAGS: 00010246
 RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 000000000000000e RCX: 0000000000000006
 RDX: 1800000000000000 RSI: 0000000000001000 RDI: ffff9730446816d0
 RBP: ffffb54cc384fa30 R08: 0000000000000800 R09: 0000000000000006
 R10: ffff9730446817f8 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffb54cc384faf8
 R13: ffffb54cc384fa78 R14: 000000000000000c R15: ffff9730446817f8
 FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff973606500000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
 CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
 CR2: 00000a520680c000 CR3: 00000005c260a005 CR4: 00000000003606e0
 DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
 DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
 Call Trace:
  pagevec_lookup_entries+0x1e/0x30
  truncate_inode_pages_range+0x127/0x960
  ? xfs_mount_validate_sb+0x440/0x500 [xfs]
  ? __inode_wait_for_writeback+0x7e/0xf0
  ? bit_waitqueue+0x40/0x40
  truncate_inode_pages_final+0x4c/0x60
  evict+0x188/0x1a0
  dispose_list+0x39/0x50
  prune_icache_sb+0x5a/0x80
  super_cache_scan+0x137/0x1b0
  shrink_slab.part.49+0x1e7/0x440
  shrink_node+0x2e1/0x2f0
  kswapd+0x2b1/0x710
  kthread+0x121/0x140
  ? mem_cgroup_shrink_node+0x190/0x190
  ? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70
  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
 Code: c7 45 a8 00 00 00 00 48 89 75 b0 45 31 ff 4d 85 ff 0f 84 01 01 00 00 49 8b 17 48 85 d2 74 69 48 89 d0 83 e0 03 0f 85 5f 01 00 00 <48> 8b 42 20 48 8d 78 ff a8 01 48 0f 44 fa 8b 47 1c 85 c0 74 d7 
 RIP: find_get_entries+0x68/0x200 RSP: ffffb54cc384f9d0
 ---[ end trace aafa3a2a2c51a63e ]---
 
Package: linux-image-4.15.0-151-generic 4.15.0-151.157
SourcePackage: linux
Tags: kernel-oops
Uname: Linux 4.15.0-151-generic x86_64
```

Kubuntu has been running VERY solid on this system for years, memtested fine, no SMART errors for drives, etc.  I can only narrow this down to the new kernel updates.

For now, the only solution I thought of was to set GRUB to boot the old kernel by default and kept the new kernel available in case I wanted to try to tinker with it some more.  For this, I used the solution illustrated here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198003/set-default-kernel-in-grub

Answer (score 1):

Also have the same problem with 4.15.0-151-generic. Fixed by reverting to previous kernel 4.15.0-147.
Note: I have an old? AMD processor AMD Ryzen 7 1700 stepping 1  microcode : 0x8001138.
This bug is similar to a previous problem
kernel.org bugzilla Bug 206487.

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of Stefan Bader and confirmed by myself as the original reporter:-

This bug was fixed in the package linux - 4.15.0-153.160

---

linux (4.15.0-153.160) bionic; urgency=medium

- bionic/linux: 4.15.0-153.160 -proposed tracker (LP: #1938319)
- 4.15.0-151 is freezing various CPUs (LP: #1938013)

  - mac80211: fix memory corruption in EAPOL handling

-- Stefan Bader  Thu, 29 Jul 2021 08:26:59 +0200